# limit a foreach with while

Tags: node.js, while-loop

I'm trying to use a while in the forEach to limit the result that I see in the view this code works but I want to limit it to show me 6 post not all

```
 feed.items.forEach(function(post) {
                        var post = {
                            _id: {
                                post_url: post.link,
                                title: {
                                    main: post.title
                                },
                                media_cover: post.enclosure.url,
                                iconSite: '',
                                date_publish: Moment.tz(post.pubDate).format('ddd, DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'ddd, DD MMMM YY HH:mm:ss ZZ'),
                            }
                        };
                        data_block.posts.push(post);
                    });
```

This is what I have tried but it does not work

```
feed.items.forEach(function(post) {
                        var c = 0
                        while (c < 6) {
                            var post = {
                                _id: {
                                    post_url: post.link,
                                    title: {
                                        main: post.title
                                    },
                                    media_cover: post.enclosure.url,
                                    iconSite: '',
                                    date_publish: Moment.tz(post.pubDate).format('ddd, DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'ddd, DD MMMM YY HH:mm:ss ZZ'),
                                }
                            };
                            c++
                        }
                        data_block.posts.push(post);
                    });
```

someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: **forEach** has more parameters. The second is **index** - you can check that (if (index < 6) {}), and do your code. No need for a **while** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: thanks, it served me

Answer (score 0):

**forEach()** has more parameters. The second is **index**, that you can use to check for number of elements to be displayed:

```
feed.items.forEach((post, index) => {
    if (index < 6) {
        // your code
    }
})
```